# Creating line from points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

There's a point layer which contains several points without order, I want to create a line to connect them.

I've read similar questions and I can work out with solutions using "point to path" or "point2one" plugins. However, I don't know those points' order unless I see them in the map. So I have to first see the point position in the map, then search the point and edit the order field in the point layer, finally connect them.

Is there any way I can make it easier, imaging just click the two points in the map, it connect and create line immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could simply digitize a new line vector using the points as guides. You would create a new line vector layer, start editing and use the editing tools to create a new line. If you activate "snapping" then, as the mouse cursor comes near to a point it will snap to the point. So you can get accurate results.

Read the [section](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html) on editing in the docs to understand how to do this.